# Ho to parallel dot matrix product in MATLAB in HPC

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, matrix-multiplication

I have  two matrices: `A,B`

```
A = rand(3000,3000);
B = rand(3000,2000);

for i = 1:2000
    X = A*A';
    Y = B*B';
    Z = A*B;
    A = 0.5*A;
    B = 0.5*B;
end
```

In practice, the matrix may be even larger. I try to perform iteration. Is there possible to  compute the `X, Y, Z` in paralell in one iteration since they are independent  with each other in MATLAB.

The code can be run in high performance computer. How to write parallel code?

Comment: i feel like in this example it would be better to parallelize the for loop. also it would be super easy with a [`parfor`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html) loop. You just have to calculate the `A` and `B` without the loop --> `X=(0.5^(i-1))*A * (0.5^(i-1))*A'`. Does it have to be the X,Y,Z that gets parallelized?

Comment: Actually, there is no need to use a loop. Just, first compute final `A`, and `B`: `A=0.5^1999*A; B=0.5^1999*B;` Then compute `X`, `Y`, and `Z`: `X=A*A'; Y=B*B'; Z=A*B`